# Allowing end user to use DESTDIR in my custom install command

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake and I need to make a symlink (in OS-es that have that feature) to my program.
Using what I've found here I wrote that code:

```
set(DOLAR "$")
install(CODE "execute_process( \
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink \
\"${DOLAR}{DESTDIR}${PROJECT_INSTALL_ROOT}/myProgram\" \
\"${DOLAR}{DESTDIR}${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/myProgram\" \
)")
```

It works fine, but unfortunately doesn't respect the `${DESTDIR}` variable set by the user.
If he invokes this command:

```
make DESTDIR="/home/user/myprograminstal" install
```

it still tries to make a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/myProgram`, completely ignored the `DESTDIR` variable set by user.

How to prompt CMake to use the `DESTDIR` variable in my custom install command?

Comment: Wait... `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` and `${DESTDIR}`? `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is used to set the path to install the content to. Any relative install commands install to this location. `DESTDIR` is a way of overwriting this value for certain generators. You'll probably need query the environment var when the command runs: `install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND \"${CMAKE_COMMAND}\" -E create_symlink \"\$ENV{DESTDIR}${PROJECT_INSTALL_ROOT}/myProgram\" \"\$ENV{DESTDIR}/bin/myProgram\")")`

Comment: @fabian Well, I also thought ```${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}``` includes ```${DESTDIR}```, but somehow in my tests it didn't. I tried ```${DOLAR}{CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/myProgram```, but it didn't worked too. Your suggestion with using ```$ENV``` seems to work thou, so I think I'll stick with it (unless I find a better solution) :)

Comment: The user can always specify `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` as cache variable when setting up the project with cmake. If you create a cache variable with this name, the user could also use `cmake-gui` to adjust the variable even after the project is generated.

Answer (score 2):

I have just witnessed this issue with a pbuilder build. My generated md5 checksums via `install(CODE)` were not put in the same folder as the other artifacts (I recommend to always log the path in code installs). Prefixing `\$ENV{DESTDIR}/` (note the escaped dollar) to the paths in the code fixed this.

Code snippet:

```
set(INSTALL_BASE "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/opt/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}")
# regular install respects DESTDIR
install(
  DIRECTORY  "cfg"
  DESTINATION ${INSTALL_BASE}
)

# install(CODE) does not respect DESTDIR unless its told to:
set(CODE_INSTALL_BASE "\$ENV{DESTDIR}/${INSTALL_BASE}")
set(MD5_FILE "${CODE_INSTALL_BASE}/files.md5")
install(CODE "
   message(STATUS \"Creating: ${MD5_FILE}\")
   file(REMOVE ${MD5_FILE})
   file(GLOB_RECURSE INSTALLED
      LIST_DIRECTORIES false
      RELATIVE ${CODE_INSTALL_BASE}
      ${CODE_INSTALL_BASE}/*
   )
   execute_process(
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E md5sum \${INSTALLED}
      OUTPUT_FILE ${MD5_FILE}
      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CODE_INSTALL_BASE}
   )"
)
```

Comment: In some places (e.g. `install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION)`, you need to use a leading slash-dot: `/.\$ENV{DESTDIR}`.